# Spring Webservices and Json

Tags: json, spring, web-services

Is it possible to send json and receive json using spring webservices?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) for it. It is easily pluggable into Spring and has better JSON support than many RPC style Web Service frameworks.

And [here](http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13709?uniqueTitle=false) is a guide to get it working with Spring.